# How to disable caching in JBOSS 4.0.4?

Tags: java, jsp, caching, jboss

I have JBOSS 4.0.4 up and running on Solaris 10 for my development purposes, the problem is each time I change my jsp and deploy, it is sometimes showing the old version;
A disgusting solution is to remove work directory and shutdown & restart JBOSS.
Is it any other solution to turn off caching completely in JBOSS version 4.0.4?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not on the jboss level but the JSP, add the following to your JSP (a Master page would be preferable if you use one.)

```
<%        
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
%>
```

*Note that this is not recommended for production, it will slow down your load time.
use in development only.